# Saving images in sql with php collation

Tags: php, sql, image

I am trying to save some png images in my database, but from the error i get

> near 'æÓ' at line 1

i assume it's a collation problem. The collation is set to utf8_general_ci. What collation should i use for images?

Comment: are you saving the image data or the path?

Comment: You should be storing this in a BLOB column (or preferably not at all but that's probably an off-topic debate for this question), so collation should irrelevant. You cannot put the image data directly in the query string, it is not safe and there is a *very* high probability (if not a certainty) that it will fail. You need to use [`LOAD_FILE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-functions.html#function_load-file) or a (true, not PDO emulated) prepared statement.

Comment: I will explain my situation so you can understand:
I have theese items saved in folders with a thumb.png and desc.txt in them, but i want to use sql for that, so i added a sql query in the loop that views them on the page, so the images are some i uploaded on my own. I use $t = @file_get_contents($sites[$i]."/thumb.png"); to load it, but what would you suggest?

Comment: I am kinda in a dilemma between sql and directories. I can't have all the things in sql, because then i can't edit the files in dreamweaver, but i want to have at least the descriptions in the database and not random text files.

Comment: @Dremp The problem you have with inserting the data is nothing to do with collation or where you get it from in PHP, it's all about the mechanism you use to insert it into the database. See my previous comment. FTR I would not bother with this at all and just store the paths in the database and the files on the file system but as I say, that debate is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to use images in an SQL database you should use BLOB field not TEXT.

The best practice is to store only the paths to the images, not the images themselves.

Comment: If i would put the thumbnails in a folder, how would i make it have a unique name everytime? Maybe md5(time()*rand(-time(),time())); would that work?

Comment: Or if i would want to use the id of the sql row, how would i get the auto increased id after i inserted the data?

Comment: If you want to put something from the query in a blob field don't forget to enclose it in a mysql_real_escape_string (PHP function). As DaveRandom said .. the problem is not in the collation but in how you insert the data into the BLOB field

Comment: Or something like `$blob = file_get_contents('file.png');
$bdata = addslashes($blob);`